# how can i locate an android device with a website and communicate with an application installed on it

Tags: android, content-management-system, android-notifications

android is able to locate devices and then communicate and update these device. That is the basis behind what i want to achieve. I have created a Content Management System which is a webpage that requires login details. This CMS will contain a record of all my android devices, the users of these devices and all the applications available for these devices. The CMS was constructed using html and it also uses javascript, php and mysql. each android device will have one of my applications installed on it and will be a wifi only enabled device(so that is how it will communicate with the world).
the scenario is, a device stored on my cms will be used by a user in london and they will be able to access the internet via wifi.I want to send a notification to the device using the cms and my location is . I am logged on to my cms in Scotland. 
1, What sort of code or software or technique can i implement into my cms(html code, php code, javascript code) and my android devices and or android applications(java code) that will allow me to send a notification from my cms webpage to my application?

2, how can i make sure it is sent to the right device and the right application on that devices? (i.e if i want to contact someone who has a mobile phone i use their phone number, in this case device does not have a sim card and can only connect to wifi.)

please provide me with a clear answer with links on how to achieve this and excuse my ignorance if the answer is straight forward i am new to this.
again just to make it clear i want to send notifications from my cms webpage to a specific application that i have made in android using eclipse and java on a specific android device whos only connection to the internet is via wifi.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think Google Cloud Messaging is appropriate for your problem.

Here is the link: http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html